# How to interpolate noise values on a landsat image time series using flag data?

Tags: raster, remote-sensing, landsat, cloud-cover, time-series

I need to create a function to interpolate noise values on a landsat image time series by the mean on a time span of 2 (xt+1 and xt-1).

I´m using the fmask product to detect cloud and shadow, then interpolation is applied.

For one time series:

Since c2 is the vector of fmask time series (2 for cloud and 4 for shadow), and t2 the vector of evi time series:

```
for (i in 2:(length(t2)-1)){ if (c2[i]==2 | c2[i]==4) t2[i]<-mean(c(t2[i-1], t2[i+1]))}
```

But it is not possible to do this using the calc function of raster package, because it does not works with functions with 2 parameters.

Any suggestion about how deal with this and apply this interpolation for all the pixels of the raster time series?

Comment: I guess this was supposed to work, but it still not :(

` for (i in 2:(length(stacklist)-1)){
re<-raster(stacklist[i])
re1<-raster(stacklist[i+1])
re0<-raster(stacklist[i-1])
rc<-raster(stacklist2[i])
if (rc[i]==2 | rc[i]==4)
  re[i]<-mean(c(re0[i],re1[i]))
writeRaster(re,filename =paste0(substr(stacklist[i], 48, 59), "_filtered.tif"))
} `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am only answering in case someone are interested in:
I could solve with this code:

```
for (i in 2:(length(stacklist)-1)){
 re<-raster(stacklist[i]) 
 re1<-raster(stacklist[i+1]) 
 re0<-raster(stacklist[i-1]) 
 rc<-raster(stacklist2[i]) 
 rm<-mean(re0,re1)
 re[which(rc[]==2 | rc[]==4)]<-rm[which(rc[]==2 | rc[]==4)]
 writeRaster(re,filename =paste0(substr(stacklist[i], 80, 86),"_filtered.tif"), overwrite=TRUE)}
```